# Statically linking any library causes libc to fail to be linked against

Tags: gcc, static

My system is an older NAS running 2.6.32. I have found that when using -static for any subsequent library, it will also try to statically link any other library that I might need.

When I add the -Wl,-Bdynamic flag first and then explicitly name those libraries using -lc, such as "-Wl,-Bdynamic -lc -lstdc++" then it works. So what happens is that libc and others fail to be statically linked.

The static libc on the system is called `/opt/lib/libc_nonshared.a.`

The contents of /opt/lib/libc.so is this:

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf32-littlearm)
GROUP ( /lib/libc.so.6 /opt/lib/libc_nonshared.a )
```

The gcc version is 4.2.3. The current build command I am facing adds `-dynamic` at the end but this doesn't help much. When I add some static library directly using its .a name, and not using a -l flag, then there is no issue.

The problem seems to be that the dynamic library of libc came with the NAS, but the static version sits in /opt/lib.

I run:

```
gcc hamming.c -static -L. -L/opt/lib -l:matrix.a -o hamming
```

I get:

```
/opt/lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.2.3/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [hamming] Error 1
```

when I try to use static libc as is. Were I to perform a 'hack' to link libc_nonshared.a to libc.a, it suddenly does find it. But complains:

```
hamming.c:54: undefined reference to `malloc'
hamming.c:54: undefined reference to `memset'
```

And a zillion other errors of course. As mentioned above, /opt/libc.so contains the reference to both files (dynamic and static).

For libstdc++ only a .la file exists.

Answer (score 2):

The `-static` linker flag does not take any argument. It is a boolean
flag that simply directs the linker to link no shared libraries, as
[documented](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html#Options)

> -static
>
> Do not link against shared libraries...

There is no need to explicitly direct the linker to link shared (dynamic)
libraries when it has a choice because that is the default bevaiour. If
you simply link, e.g.

```
gcc -o prog ... -lfoo ...
```

then the linker will link the first of `libfoo.so` (shared) or `libfoo.a`
(static) that it finds in any of the specified (`-Ldir`) or default
search directories, searched in commandline sequence. If it finds both
`libfoo.so` and `libfoo.a` in the same directory then it will choose
`libfoo.so`. Thus shared and static libraries may be freely intermixed
without any special options.

Specify `-static` only if you wish to link *only* static libraries.

If you wish to insist on linking a particular `libfoo.a` even when
`libfoo.so` is in the same directory and would be chosen by default,
use the explicit form of the `-l` option: `-l:libfoo.a`

**Later**

```
gcc hamming.c -static -L. -L/opt/lib -l:matrix.a -o hamming
```

This command is failing with:

```
ld: cannot find -lc
```

because the linker (`ld`) cannot find a static library `libc.a` in
any of the specified linker search directories (`-L. -L/opt/lib`) or
the default linker search directories. If you wish instead to link
`/opt/lib/libc_nonshared.a` then your command should be:

```
>gcc hamming.c -static -L. -L/opt/lib -l:matrix.a -lc_nonshared -o hamming
```

However, you have not explained why you want to link this program statically
(`-static`) in the first place, which is not the usual way and will require you to have installed
static versions of *all* libraries required for the linkage - both those
you explicitly link and the default libraries that `gcc` will add for C language
linkage (Standard C library, GCC runtime library).

Supposing you have a static library called (oddly) `matrix.a` (rather
than normally, `libmatrix.a`) that is located in `/some/dir/`, then the
normal way to compile and link your program would be:

```
gcc hamming.c -L/some/dir -l:matrix.a -o hamming
```

I suggest you start with that and deviate only as problems compel
you to.

The discovery of an `/opt/lib/libc.so` containing:

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf32-littlearm)
GROUP ( /lib/libc.so.6 /opt/lib/libc_nonshared.a )
```

is misleading you. This is not your shared `libc`. A shared library
is a binary. This is a linker script, and it says that your shared `libc`
is in fact `/lib/libc.so.6`. The linker will almost certainly find and use it by default.

Comment: What could cause static linking of e.g. libc and libstd++ to break?

Comment: @Xennex81 It would depend what you mean by "break". One can only speculate
on why a particular linkage command is failing without seeing
the failing linkage command and the all errors that follow from it.
If you add that information, verbatim, in the body of your question you
will probably get exactly the right answer.

Comment: @Xennex81 You've added an error message but not the command you ran that produced it.

Comment: Initially I just used -static because it was referenced in a tutorial. Yesterday I was compiling something (made by another) that failed for the same reason. Although I have no need at this point to statically link against libc, I thank you for the answer on how to do that.

Comment: It still doesn't work though. The -lc_nonshared fails in the same way as direct reference to libc_nonshared.a on the command line, ie. with a long list of symbol not found errors. It cannot find any refrerences in libc.